# Case statement not working as expected

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I have one single file called `Exercises.rb`

```
def ask(prompt)
  print prompt, ' '
  $stdout.flush
  s = gets
  return s
end

def myreverse(s)
  aux=""
  for i in 0..s.length-1
    aux=s[i] + aux
  end
  return aux
end

def mywordreverse(s)
  aux=[]
  s=s.split(" ")
  for i in 0..s.length-1
    aux.unshift(s[i])
  end
  return aux.join(" ")
end

def choose(s,option)
  case option
    when 1 then print myreverse(s)
    when 2 then print mywordreverse(s)
    when 3 then print "hello"
    else print "You gave me #{option} -- I have no idea what to do with that."
  end
end

s=ask("Write a string to reverse: ")
option=ask("Choose an option. 1 - Reverse string. 2 - Reverse String words : ")

choose(s,option)
```

I am always getting `You gave MYCHOSENOPTION -- I have no idea what to do with that.`, no matter what option I choose. If I put an `if` just before the `case` comparing 1, it just doesn't seem to be matching the option to my strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, here is how I would write this program:

```
def ask(prompt)
  print "#{prompt} "
  gets.chomp
end

def myreverse(s)
  s.reverse
end

def mywordreverse(s)
  s.split(' ').reverse.join(' ')
end

def choose(s,option)
  case option
    when 1 then puts myreverse(s)
    when 2 then puts mywordreverse(s)
    when 3 then puts "hello"
    else        puts "You gave me #{option}; I don't know what to do with that."
  end
end

$stdout.sync
str    = ask("Write a string to reverse: ")
option = ask("Choose an option:\n1: Reverse string\n2: Reverse String words\n>")
choose(str,option.to_i)
```

Notes:

1. The last expression in a method *is* the return value; using `return` is almost never needed or desirable in Ruby.
2. There exist built-in methods for reversing strings and arrays. (I understand if you are doing this for an exercise.)
3. It is cumbersome to iterate arrays or strings in Ruby using `for`. Instead, you should use

   ```ruby
   my_str.each_char do |char|
     # use the single-character string `char` here
   end

   my_array.each do |item|
     # use the item here
   end
   ```
4. You can use `$stdout.sync` to force output to always be flushed.
5. You need to use `chomp` on your string to remove the trailing newline always included when the user presses Enter.
6. As pointed out by @robbrit, the core of your problem is that the return value of `gets` is a String, and you are comparing it to a Fixnum. I've used `to_i` in my code above to convert the string to an integer for comparison.
7. I've used `puts` instead of `print` for the output so that I get a newline at the end and do not leave the user with their next command prompt on the same line as the output.

Comment: Hi Phrogz, I actually thought i knew my answer, but i am so fond of yours, that i will stick with it. My first problem was that comparison 1 === "1" is actually false. My second problem was that chomp, which was missing, and that one took me a hard time. I actually got there by checking the length of my option string. As for point 2, and 3, you have a keen eye :-). I created these ones to support an interview process, abstract to the language, so i answered it the most low-level/nearer to C way. In each language (and i like ruby more and more btw ) there will be different ways to solve this.

Comment: Anyhow, i have learned from your answer and thank you for it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 case option.to_i
    # rest of your code...
```

In Ruby, `1 == "1"` (or more specifically in the case of a `case` statement, `1 === "1"`) always evaluates to `false`. You'll need to convert one of them so that they are the same type before doing the comparison. The value that you're passing in for `option` is likely a `String` and will therefore fail for any comparisons to integers.

Comment: Hi, thank you robbrit. That actually was my first dilemma, and I switched from 1,2,3 to "1","2","3" (actually 1,2, the 3 was just a test). to_i would solve that one problem though. What would be more efficient, convert to int, or compare the chars ?

Comment: In theory comparing the strings would be more efficient because you're not having to parse anything, however the difference is so miniscule that I doubt it would actually matter.