# Mr. Ruby, Ms Rails, my json created record is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, post, httparty

this newbie here is smacking his head with webservices over Rails. 
Perhaps someone could ease my pain?

I've created a simple rails app, and generated the scaffold MyRecords. Then I'm trying to create a record over irb with the code below :

testWS.rb

```
require 'HTTParty'

class MyRecordCreate
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'localhost:3000'

  def initialize(u, p)
    @auth = {:username => u, :password => p}
  end

  def post(text)
    options = { :body => { name:text} }
    self.class.post('/my_records', options)
  end
end


response = HTTParty.get("http://localhost:3000/my_records/new.json")
print response

record = MyRecordCreate.new("","").post("test remote record")
print record
```

With the code above, I managed to create a record. the thing is that my Record (which only has the column "name") is created with an empty name!

Any suggestions on this one?

I'm longing to slice this despair piece by piece.

Thank you for your contribute.

Comment: Please, make proper informative titles. I improved your previous question, you fix this one.

Comment: Also, pay more attention to code formatting.

Comment: S/O: all ye who enter, beware that no one is allowed to have a sense of humor...

Comment: Hi Sergio, I'm sorry, but i do am a bit lost here. What previous question was that? As for the title, "I am just trying to create a record over json", i would guess this says it all.. Ok, so i even mentioned i was using Ruby and Rails for this....and i did in the form of a dialogue... I meant no disrespect...although from your answer, it seems that way. Could you be a bit more constructive? Thank you. I have "just" discovered StackOverflow, and any help on the formatting and what-else will be most appreciated. Cheers

Comment: I think Sergio's point is that the anthropomorphizing of a programming language does not get other readers any closer to your question at hand.

Comment: @itsalltime: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193710/case-statement-not-working-as-expected). As for my comment: current title does not say it all. In fact, there are only 2 relevant words there: create and record. `json` is in the tags, as are `ruby` and `rails` (and as `httparty` should be), the rest is just visual noise. The title should be as concise as possible.

Comment: @itsalltime: regarding formatting, I did it here, look at edit history of this question, you'll be able to compare. (your code was mostly ok, but was indented too much and your require line was indented way more than it should be).

Comment: @Sergio, thank you for your comments. The title wasn't exhaustive actually, and now i think it is. Would you agree? As for the Mr Ruby, Ms Rails and the json, although they are also tags, i believe they put some context on it, and the anthropomorphic way (thanks @Charles) of writing the title is just a way to catch the reader's eye. Anyway, If it breaks any kind of rule, please do say, and i will put it on a more formal way.

Comment: Read [this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title), you'll get some insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these two lines to your HTTParty class:

```
format :json
headers "Accept" => "application/json"
```

These tell httparty and the remote service to which it connects to send and receive JSON. For your example (with .json at the end of the URL) it isn't necessary to add the second line, but I find it is good practice and keep it anyway.

The next problem is that Rails expects your uploaded data to be inside the top level name of your object. So, for your example, the options line should look something like:

```
options = { :body => { :person => { :name => text } } }
```

Replace `person` with the name of the model that you are attempting to create.

Comment: This is just great, I've tested it and it works:-), and it makes perfect sense....Do you know where i can find more extensive documentation on HTTParty uses? I just found it so hard to answer this one...and it seems pretty simple... I actually tested without the headers line, and although the record was created, the output was a parsing error...What does the format :json actually does? would it be the same to write headers 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ? Cheers, and Thank you. You've just helped my cut off a slice of despair. I am now back on the path to freedom ;-).

Comment: The best documentation out there that I have found is their rdocs: http://httparty.rubyforge.org/rdoc/
http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty

However, if you learn by example like I do their examples are quite helpful: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/examples

Comment: Thanks Daniel..I thought i had seen those examples already, but on a second look i have found more great ones that might help me go forward. Thank you once again for your help. Cheers